# как хранить метки, ключевые слова к посту блога в бд

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Как мне хранить ключевые слова, чтобы можно было делать поиск поста не только по одному ключевому слову но и по несколько.

Структура таблица с постами

```
id | title | text | imglink
```

Если добавить столбец labels и записывать туда строкой ключевые слова, например : template1;template2.

То можно ли будет искать пост по ключевым словам

Если создать новую таблицу, как мне хранить несколько ключевых слов?

Comment: Используйте новую таблицу со столбцами `post_id`, `keyword`(одно слово!).

Comment: Добавление второй таблицы тоже никак не помешает искать по нескольким ключевым словам.

Comment: Если создать новую таблицу, как мне хранить несколько ключевых слов?

Comment: 123|слово1, 123|слово2, 123|слово3 - очень просто